# Webkit polyfill for IE10/11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webkit

IE now support most of the stuff webkit does, but it will not work as long as the developers use webkit prefixes for things. Also, IE use pointer events, and not  touch events.

Did anybody attempt to create a JavaScript that can make a webkit specific site work on IE? I want to inject that script and spoof the user agent string in a web browser I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Sites today no longer rely on user agent strings to detect functionality. They use feature detection, either manually, or using libraries like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com).

If a site is using things like this, with no feature detection:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
```

Then it's poorly designed, or intended to work only in a controlled environment (like it was done with IE long ago -- and it's still done, in intranets --).

You could redefine some methods to make that line work in IE, for example:

```
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;
```

But this won't solve problems you may find in CSS, or setting style properties in javascript. Doing

```
element.style.webkitTransform = element.style.transform;
```

won't do you any good, unfortunately.

Comment: Most google websites do user agent detection. As a consequence, on Windows Phone you get the noscript version of Gmail, even though the desktop version of Gmail works fine on windows phone. You get fewer options on google.com as well. But I was hoping to find a script that fixes many of these things out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. I don't expect every old website to be rewritten to fix this issue either - so there is a market for this script.